# How do you build a wpdb query dynamically?

Tags: wpdb

My table has 6 columns, 3 of which I'm interested in: `id, name, email`. The problem is that my query does care about the `name`, but doesn't always care about `email` or `id`.

As of now, the code is this:

```php
  function get_people( $name, $id = null, $name = null) {

    global $wpdb

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'my_table';

    $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE name='%s'";

    if(!is_null($id)) {
        $query .= "AND id='%s'";
    }

    return $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->query(
        $query,
        $id
    ));
  }
```

However, WP is telling me this:
`wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query does not contain the correct number of placeholders (1) for the number of arguments passed (3). Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 4.8.3.)`

And, of course, the query looks really ugly and not dynamic at all. If I want changes, it'd be hell to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I see you're trying to prepare a statement but I don't see `$wpdb->prepare()`. Check out the docs on [`WPDB::prepare()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I was actually wondering about it, because *for some reason* I recalled `get_results` wrapping it all and not having to care.

Comment: From my understanding ( and looking at the code of [`WPDB::get_results()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/) I don't think any of the WPDB methods call prepare for you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee You're right, good to know. This wouldn't have passed code review then, but as of now, really just trying to build the PoC and this dynamic query business is iffy.

Comment: Another possible issue: I think your `$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->query(...` should simply be `$wpdb->get_results( $query ...`.